# Python Convert JSON to Python Object

Tags: python, json, class

I have the following code. In the class LegoThemes "saveThemes()" I do a JSON dump and output is a .JSON file - this works perfectly (thanks to help on another thread!). However, when I have implemented the method LoadThemes() it currently simply loads the python into self.__themes. However, what I want to do is to create a LegoTheme object for every JSON entry in the file "themes.json".

```
import json


class LegoThemes:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__themes = []
        self.loadThemes()

    def saveThemes(self):
        with open("themes.json", "w") as themesStorageFile:
            json.dump([t.__dict__ for t in self.__themes], themesStorageFile, indent=4)

    def loadThemes(self):
        with open("themes.json") as themesStorageFile:
            self.__themes = json.load(themesStorageFile)

    def addTheme(self, theme):
        self.__themes.append(theme)
        self.saveThemes()

    def getThemeTitlesList(self):
        themeTitlesList = []
        for theme in self.__themes:
            print(theme)


class LegoTheme:
    def __init__(self, title, description, thumbnailImage, logoImage, url):
        self.__title = title
        self.__description = description
        self.__thumbnailImage = thumbnailImage
        self.__logoImage = logoImage
        self.__url = url

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.__title


legoThemes = LegoThemes()

print(legoThemes.getThemeTitlesList())
```

Also, the content of themes.json for completeness:

```
[
    {
        "_LegoTheme__title": "Title1",
        "_LegoTheme__description": "Description1",
        "_LegoTheme__thumbnailImage": "ThumbnailImage1",
        "_LegoTheme__logoImage": "LogoImage1",
        "_LegoTheme__url": "URL1"
    },
    {
        "_LegoTheme__title": "Title2",
        "_LegoTheme__description": "Description2",
        "_LegoTheme__thumbnailImage": "ThumbnailImage2",
        "_LegoTheme__logoImage": "LogoImage2",
        "_LegoTheme__url": "URL2"
    },
    {
        "_LegoTheme__title": "Title3",
        "_LegoTheme__description": "Description3",
        "_LegoTheme__thumbnailImage": "ThumbnailImage3",
        "_LegoTheme__logoImage": "LogoImage3",
        "_LegoTheme__url": "URL3"
    }
]
```

Comment: `[LegoTheme(*obj.values()) for obj in json.load(open(filename))]` *(one-liner is just for example, do not use this in real code because file handle will left opened)*

Comment: @OlvinRoght how would I go about organising it into a structure using a with statement - this has me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpack values of each dict to `LegoGame` constructor:

```py
import json
...
with open(filename) as f:
    lst = json.load(f)

result = [LegoTheme(*obj.values()) for obj in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
d = {
    "_LegoTheme__title": "Title1",
    "_LegoTheme__description": "Description1",
    "_LegoTheme__thumbnailImage": "ThumbnailImage1",
    "_LegoTheme__logoImage": "LogoImage1",
    "_LegoTheme__url": "URL1"
}
```

We can write a generic conversion function:

```
def remove_prefix(prefix, d):
    return {k[len(prefix):] : v for k, v in d.items() if prefix in k}
```

declare a dataclass:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class LegoTheme:
     title: str
     description: str
     thumbnailImage: str
     logoImage: str
     url: str
```

and convert it to a dataclass with:

```py
lego_theme = LegoTheme(**remove_prefix("_LegoTheme__", d))
```

so you can access it like:

```py
lego_theme.title
lego_theme.description
lego_theme.thumbnailImage
lego_theme.logoImage
lego_theme.url
```